# In a web application,does a method of a class that converts a Bean to an DTO are synchronized or should I create an instance of this class?

Tags: java, web-applications, synchronization, converters, static-methods

I have a doubt!

I would like to use a class with JavaBean to DTO converter methods and vice versa.

Is my web application, should the methods be synced or should I create an instance of this class when I want to use them?

This is the javabean:

```
        public class Person {

        private String name;

        private String surname;

        public String getName() {
           return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
        }

        public String getSurname() {
            return surname;
        }

        public void setSurname (String surname) {
           this.surname = surname;
        }

        }
```

This is the dto:

```
        public class PersonDTO {

        private String fullName;

        public String getFullName() {
           return fullName;
        }

        public void setFullName(String fullName) {
           this.fullName = fullName;
        }

        }
```

This is the converter class:

```
        public class PersonConverter {

        public static PersonDTO fromBeanToDTO (Person Person) {

        PersonDTO personDTO = new PersonaDTO();

        personDTO.setFullName(person.getNome() + " " + person.getSurname());

        return personDTO;

        }

        }
```

Comment: Why do you need the DTO class in the first place? Couldn't Person have a method for getting the full name?

Comment: It's just an example code to simplify